# Reactivemongo - where is |>>> operator defined?

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

Reading http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/consume-streams.html it states

> The apply method on Enumerator has an operator alias, |>>>. So we can
>   rewrite the last line like this: enumeratorOfPeople |>>>
>   processDocuments.

Where is this operator defined within API doc ?

Reading https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Enumerator$.html defines apply as :

```
def
apply [E] (in: E*): Enumerator[E]
Create an Enumerator from a set of values
```

But no mention of |>>> operator ?

Comment: Not specific to ReactiveMongo, but to Play Iteratee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a typo.

The alias for [`apply`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator@apply[A](i:play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]):scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]]) is called [`|>>`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator@|>>[A](i:play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]):scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]]). [`|>>>`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator@|>>>[A](i:play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]):scala.concurrent.Future[A]) is something slightly different.

Note: you were looking at the documentation for the [`Enumerator` object](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$). You need to look at the [`Enumerator` trait](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator). Also, you were looking at outdated documentation (2.0).

There is an icon in the top-left corner of the Scaladoc that tells you what you are looking at:

- [image: class] class
- [image: class with companion object] class with companion object (click to toggle)
- [image: trait] trait
- [image: trait with companion object] trait with companion object (click to toggle)
- [image: object] object
- [image: companion object for a class] companion object for a class (click to toggle)
- [image: companion object for a trait] companion object for a trait (click to toggle)
- [image: companion object for an abstract type] companion object for an abstract type (click to toggle)
- [image: package] package
- [image: abstract type] abstract type
- [image: abstract type with companion object] abstract type with companion object (click to toggle)

Comment: 'The alias for apply is called |>>' is this a Scala pattern? I don't see the difference between an 'apply alias' and a new method similar to apply : apply signature - '(i: Iteratee[E, A]): Future[Iteratee[E, A]]' while '|>>' signature is similar - '|>>[A](i: Iteratee[E, A]): Future[Iteratee[E, A]]'

Comment: No, this is not a Scala pattern. The Play developers decided to create a method named `|>>` that does the same thing as `apply`. That's all there is to it. As you can see, [the definition in the source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Enumerator.scala#L40) is just `def |>>[A](i: Iteratee[E, A]): Future[Iteratee[E, A]] = apply(i)` Note: the signature is not similar, it is identical, and the `|>>` method simply calls `apply`.

Comment: what is the use of the apply method in this case ? As creating a new Enumerator using apply : Enumerator[play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument,String]](myFunction) is not a usable function because the Enumerator value has not been set ?